# Optimistic updates in RTK query do not work when updating only one user

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have set up a basic RTK query API CRUD for optimistic updates.

I want to update the draft manually before receiving the response so that I can provide an optimistic update to the user.

However, I am encountering an issue where the draft function is not running.

```
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import api from '../api'

export type User = {
    userId: number
    name: string
    username: string
}

const usersAdaptor = createEntityAdapter<User>({
    selectId: (model) => model.userId,
})

const initialState = usersAdaptor.getInitialState()

const extendedUsersAPI = api.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllUsers: builder.query<EntityState<User>, undefined | void>({
            query: () => ({ url: '/users', method: 'GET' }),
            transformResponse: (result: User[]) =>
                usersAdaptor.setAll(initialState, result),

            providesTags: (result?: EntityState<User>) =>
                result
                    ? [
                          { type: 'Users', id: 'LIST' },
                          ...result.ids.map((id) => ({
                              type: 'Users' as const,
                              id,
                          })),
                      ]
                    : [{ type: 'Users', id: 'LIST' }],
        }),

        getSingleUser: builder.query<EntityState<User>, number>({
            query: (userId) => ({ url: '/users/' + userId, method: 'GET' }),

            transformResponse: (result: User) =>
                usersAdaptor.setOne(initialState, result),
            providesTags: (_result, _meta, id) => [{ type: 'Users', id }],
        }),
        updateUser: builder.mutation<void, User>({
            query: (user) => ({
                url: `/users/${user.userId}`,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: user,
            }),

            async onQueryStarted(
                { userId, ...patch },
                { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
            ) {
                const patchResult = dispatch(
                    extendedUsersAPI.util.updateQueryData(
                        'getSingleUser',
                        userId,
                        (draft) => {
                            console.log('sc') // <------------ never runs!
                            Object.assign(draft, patch)
                        }
                    )
                )
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled
                } catch {
                    patchResult.undo()
                }
            },
        }),
        addNewUser: builder.mutation<EntityState<User>, Partial<User>>({
            query: (user) => ({ url: '/users', method: 'POST', data: user }),

            invalidatesTags: (_result, _error, arg) => [
                { type: 'Users', id: arg.userId },
            ],
        }),
    }),
})

export const {
    useGetAllUsersQuery,
    useLazyGetAllUsersQuery,
    useAddNewUserMutation,
    useUpdateUserMutation,
} = extendedUsersAPI
```

The problem is that when I update a user and use the `updateQueryData` method to dispatch the update, the code inside the `onQueryStarted` function doesn't execute because of the `getSingleUser` call. However, if I change it to `getAllUsers`, the optimistic update works correctly.

```
{
// ...
updateUser: builder.mutation<void, User>({
         query: (user) => ({
            url: `/users/${user.userId}`,
            method: 'PUT',
            data: user,
         }),

         async onQueryStarted(
            { userId, ...patch },
            { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
         ) {
            const patchResult = dispatch(
               extendedUsersAPI.util.updateQueryData(
                  'getAllUsers',
                  undefined,
                  (draft) => {
                     console.log('sc') // <------------ this runs!
                     Object.assign(draft, patch)
                  }
               )
            )
            try {
               await queryFulfilled
            } catch {
               patchResult.undo()
            }
         },
      }),
}
```

You can find a similar example in the [RTK Query documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates#optimistic-updates) under the section of "Optimistic Updates".

Being able to run the optimistic update with updating only single user.